# Illegal block size exception while decrypting the encrypted message digest

Tags: java, exception, encryption, rsa, message-digest

I want to decrpyt the encrypted message digest. i hav this code in my java program:

```
 String bobSignedMsg = SignedMsg;

    //At the receiving end, Bob extracts the msg 
    // length, the msg text, and the digital
    // signature from the signed msg.
    //Get the message length.
    int MsgLen = Integer.parseInt(bobSignedMsg.trim().substring(bobSignedMsg.length()-6));
    System.out.println(
               "\n12. Bob's calculated msg len: "
                                 + MsgLen);

    //Get the message text.
    String bobMsgText = bobSignedMsg.substring(
                                 0,MsgLen);
    System.out.println(
               "\n13. Bob's extracted msg text: "
                             + bobMsgText);

    //Bob knows that everything following the msg
    // text except for the four characters at the
    // end that indicate the message length is
    // the encoded and encrypted version of the
    // extended digital signature.  He extracts
    // it.
     String bobExtractedSignature =
          bobSignedMsg.substring(
            MsgLen,bobSignedMsg.length() - 6);
    System.out.println(
        "\n14. Bob's extracted extended digital "
                    + "signature: " 
                        + bobExtractedSignature);
    byte[] strtodecrypt=bobExtractedSignature.getBytes();

            byte[] decryptedCardNo = obj.rsaDecrypt(strtodecrypt,PbkeyPath);
         String decryptedform = obj.byteArrayToHexStr(decryptedCardNo);
         System.out.println("After Decryption: "+decryptedform);
```

In the above lines of code

```
byte[] decryptedCardNo = obj.rsaDecrypt(strtodecrypt,PbkeyPath);
```

calls the function:

```
public byte[] rsaDecrypt(byte[] sampleText,String pbkeypath) {
    PublicKey pubKey = null;
    try {
        pubKey = readKeyFromFile(pbkeypath);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Cipher cipher = null;
    try {
        cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, pubKey);
    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    byte[] cipherData = null;
    try {
        cipherData = cipher.doFinal(sampleText);
        // cipherData = cipher.
    } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return cipherData;
}
```

But it gives the following error:

```
javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Data must not be longer than 128 bytes
at com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.a(DashoA13*..)
at com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.engineDoFinal(DashoA13*..)
at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(DashoA13*..)
```

I dont understand how to resolve the error for block size exception.....Please if anybody can help me with some ideas it wud be a great help in my project.

Comment: Your function name talks about signatues, and the code uses RSA encryption. That doesn't fit together. To sign with RSA, you need a scheme like RSA-PSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Block ciphers, such as RSA, can only encrypt no more than *blockSize* bytes. If you want to encrypt an arbitrary large amount of data with the same key, you would split it to parts of *blockSize* and encrypt each block individually. The same applies to decryption.

Comment: I wouldn't call RSA a block cipher, even if it operates on blocks. It's almost never a good idea to split a message into blocks, and apply RSA to each of them.